# My site shows menus based on a users privs. I have a function that returns the privs as a dictionary as below:

Tags: django, dynamic, sidebar, privileges

i need to show my sidebar dynamically by using 6 privilages which giving by admin to users. this is my views.py which i set in my django function.i used checkbox to select 6 privilages here.privilages are ecom,service,career,course,blog,offline.
for admin status=1,subadmin status=2.

```
def SIDEMENU(request):
# ii=request.session['sid']

a=db_coslogin.objects.all().filter(ecom=1,status=2)
b=db_coslogin.objects.all().filter(blog=1,status=2)
c=db_coslogin.objects.all().filter(servive=1,status=2)
d=db_coslogin.objects.all().filter(offline=1,status=2)
e=db_coslogin.objects.all().filter(career=1,status=2)
f=db_coslogin.objects.all().filter(course=1,status=2)

return render(request, "sidebar.html",{'ecomr':a,'blog':b,'servive':c,'offline':d,'career':e,'course':f})
```

models.py

```
class db_coslogin(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)


name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
password = models.CharField(max_length=100)


type1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
is_delete = models.IntegerField(default=0)
ecom = models.IntegerField(default=0)
service = models.IntegerField(default=0)
career = models.IntegerField(default=0)
cource = models.IntegerField(default=0)
offline = models.IntegerField(default=0)
blog = models.IntegerField(default=0)
status = models.IntegerField(default=0)




class Meta:
    db_table = "db_coslogin"
```

Comment: if anyone can help me..do it soon as possible..please

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: here i added models.py.

Comment: Thanks. As a side note, models are, by convention, normally named with capital letters. For example: `DBCosLogin`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using your existing model and view, you could do something like this in the template:

```html
{% if ecomr.0.ecom %}
  {% include 'ecom_menu.html' %}
{% elif blog.0.blog %}
  {% include 'blog_menu.html' %}
{% else %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

However, I would strongly suggest reading into Django's built in permissions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions. This will allow you to write cleaner code and will, more importantly, be more secure.